# A Element to RootPanel

Tags: html, gwt

how can I add a `Element` to the `RootPanel`? Is creating a `HTML` element from the Elements.toString() method really the only way?

Import names:

- `Element (com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element)`
- `RootPanel (com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel)`
- `HTML (com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML)`

Regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use widgets when what you want are elements.

```java
Document.get().getBody().appendChild(element);
```

or

```java
Document.get().getElementById("foo").appendChild(element);
```

Comment: any advantage in using this comapared to jonic answer? Or just for clear coding style (So choose Widgets or Elements and stick to it in your application)

Comment: It's not about sticking to either elements or widgets, but about avoiding mixing them in unintended usage. Widgets are supposed to control their DOM subtree and messing with it can break them. Admittedly RootPanel is a special beast, as it might not be empty when created, so in that case its more for _clean coding style_ than anything else. In your case, I believe my proposed approach is the one that best fit your need: I want to add an element as a child of the body, or of the element with X; using RootPanel's getElement to get that element seems just wrong. Otherwise, no, no advantage.

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
RootPanel.get().getElement().appendChild(element);
```